# Why wont Visual Studio Code show build errors

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, build, ide, build-error

So I've been using VScode, and VS for a awhile now but I realized for some odd reason it doesnt seem to want to show me build errors anymore.

Has anyone ever noticed this and found a fix? I tried searching on here; but there were literally 7 VSCode related questions, none of which were applicable to my situation.

I have tried:

- Going View > Restart Omni Sharp.
- Crtl + Shft + M; to view problems.

I'm don't think I ever downloaded any extensions for this either before.

Current code:
[image]

As you can see its not asking to resolve [Required] by adding: 
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

It used to display a red squiggle, and then you could hover over it or press Ctrl + space / Ctrl +  . and it would suggest adding the using statements/imports/etc.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you figured this out? It was showing up for me automatically at first, but now I can't find it !?

Comment: @Danimal111 well its been awhile since I asked; but I believe at some point I reinstalled VSCode and I remember things went back to normal for me after that. Although I think rebuilding the project worked as well a few times. But I can’t remember if that was before or after the reinstallation… try reinstalling VScode :) hope that works for you!